# Error Importing Third Party Python Libraries

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro, installation

I was able to create a clone environment of the ArcGIS Pro (v. 2.9.5) default environment, arcgispro-py3 and import the libraries I need into the clone environment, such as geopandas. However, when I tested the installed libraries, I received the error message below.

How do I resolve it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\tmpham\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from geopandas.io.file import _read_file as read_file  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\tmpham\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 12, in <module>
    import fiona
  File "C:\Users\tmpham\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    with fiona._loading.add_gdal_dll_directories():
AttributeError: module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading'
```

Comment: You don't state which version of Pro you are using? Also have you made your cloned environment the active environment?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS Pro v. 2.9.5. Yes, I have made the clone environment the active environment.

Comment: Try `import fiona` before geopandas https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/944#issuecomment-806362135

Comment: You might need to check if gdal is installed properly and the path to the gdal is available to conda. https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/how-to-install-gdal-with-anaconda/